# Errno 4 on centos 5.6 server

Tags: centos, samba

I try to install samba on my centos server and it shows me this code:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5&arch=i386&repo=os error was
[Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-2, 'Name or service not known')>
```

I uncommented baseurl on `/etc/yum.repose.d/CentOS-Base.repo` but its still the same. I checked nameservers and they are ok. Why this might be happend?
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you checked nameservers?

1. Try to see if your nameservers responds correctly:

   ```
   host mirrorlist.centos.org
   ```
2. Try to see if world nameservers responds correctly (Google's in this example):

   ```
   host mirrorlist.centos.org 8.8.8.8
   ```
3. Be sure your nameservers are correct in `/etc/resolv.conf` and are ones that respond correctly to requests for `mirrorlist.centos.org`.

Nothing more I can tell here since you didn't put your `/etc/resolv.conf` file contents in your question and there are missing details (how you're connecting? Directly to the Internet? via your router with DNS provided by that router? VPN maybe?

Comment: Sorry for luck of information but i am tottally new in linux so..

This is my /etc/resolv.conf file

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 208.67.222.222
I am connecting to internet through a mikrotik ,and as i know i have no filters on internet.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for luck of information but i am tottally new in linux so..

This is my /etc/resolv.conf file

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 208.67.222.222
```

I am connecting to internet through a mikrotik ,and as i know i have no filters on internet.